# Accessing Linux NFS Shares using Windows Explorer

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, samba, nfs

I have a Linux Machine (CentOS 6.4) using which I exported a NFS Share.

I'm pretty sure that this is an NFS Share since I

- Created an entry in /etc/exports
- Ran the command exportfs -avr

Now when I try to access this share from Windows ,

1. What protocol is it using ? SMB ?
2. If it's using SMB to access the share then I'm guessing Windows has no clue about the nature of the
   Underlying File System Correct ?
3. Does Windows Explorer/OS know that this share is hosted   on a Linux File System (is it NFS or EXT4) ? NFS is a File System or is it a protocol ?

I'm pretty confused by this Linux and Windows interaction. I have "Services for NFS" installed on my Windows Machine which is running on Server 2008.

Can some please explain how it all works ? I can pickup the answers from a proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share files from linux to windows it'll be better using SAMBA. Samba is supported directly in windows. If you need to access a NFS share from a windows computer you need a NFS client.

So if you only need access to the share from windows - then use SAMBA.

Comment: Will Windows come to know about the underlying File System ?